# Listbox item click animation toolkit?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there some toolkit for the animation when a user clicks on a list box item? The animation that I am referring to is when you tap on a list box item (like an email in your inbox) and the text depresses under your finger (or topple? its kind of hard to describe). I see this in many Windows Phone 7 applications like Yelp, OneBusAway, GoVoice, etc and was wondering if there was some toolkit for this animation or if I have to develop this animation on my own.

If anyone know if such a toolkit exists or not please let me know! I could do this using storyboards but I don't want to reinvent the wheel unless I have to :).

Thanks!
Haji

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be Tilt Effect. Detailed here.

[Tilt Effect Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941094)

Comment: Oh great! This is what I was looking for, Thanks! I should read official documentation some more...

Comment: Does anyone possibly know why, when i click on a listitem that is using tilt effect it turns red? And it stays red untill i click on the next one. The tilt animation, hover, is still displayed.

Answer (score 3):

The Silverlight Toolkit has this functionality built in.

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/